# Is there a way to annoate a layout with the file source in indesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign, indesign-scripting

Is there a way to print / export a indesign file as a pdf or other but first annotate any images with the file source ie. `user/documents/images.. etc` so that whens its printed / exported it will say what the source is for each image by the side / ontop of the image.

Answer (score 1):

I used a javascript for this purpose in CS1/3/5.5. I'm not aware of any built in way to do it.

I can't find my oldie around anywhere, but the [Adobe InDesign scripting forum](http://forums.adobe.com/community/indesign/indesign_scripting) is usually a treasure trove. I think [**this one**](http://forums.adobe.com/message/4011050#4011050) is at least a start. Here's the final code from that discussion.

```
var tgt = app.activeDocument.rectangles;
for (i=0;i<tgt.length;i++){
myCaption = app.activeDocument.textFrames.add();
myCaption.textFramePreferences.verticalJustification =
    VerticalJustification.BOTTOM_ALIGN
myCaption.contents = tgt[i].graphics[0].itemLink.name
myCaption.paragraphs[0].justification =
    Justification.CENTER_ALIGN;
bnds = tgt[i].visibleBounds;
myCaption.visibleBounds =
    [bnds[0]-6, bnds[1], bnds[0]-1,bnds[3]];
}
```

Comment: *your javascript

Comment: I'll have to dig around a bit. I'll update my answer if/when I can find something.

Comment: Answer updated.